# How can I find where a header is referenced in a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference, find-in-files

I inserted a lot of cross references in my word document.
*(in the Insert ribben, the links group, select Cross Reference)*

Is there a way to find out where I refered a certain paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserted cross references can be searched by their reference numbers.

For seeing those codes, you must enable "Show field codes instead of their values"
in ribbon *File > Options > Advanced* under section
*Show document content*.

Cross references will then be displayed as `{REF Bookmark-name \h }`,
and then you can search the document for `Bookmark-name`.

You can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
to turn on/off field codes currently on the page.
To turn off a field code for a specific field, click on the reference and press
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
instead, or right-click the reference and select "Toggle Field Codes".

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Tis works fine for references to bookmarks. For references to headers, the reference now looks like `{ REF _Ref18487841 \r \h }`. Is there an easier way to find this `18487841` than to temporarily temporary add a new reference the same header?

Comment: I don't know of one.